# Writing a Java Method for Mysql use

Tags: java, mysql, methods

These tables contain information about various machinery parts stored in dierent warehouse
locations:

```
CREATE TABLE part (
pid: integer,
description: varchar(128),
PRIMARY KEY (pid)
) Engine = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE warehouse (
wid: integer,
address: varchar(128),
PRIMARY KEY (wid)
) Engine = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE stock (
pid: INTEGER,
wid: INTEGER,
quantity: INTEGER,
unitcost: FLOAT
FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES part (pid),
FOREIGN KEY (wid) REFERENCES warehouse (wid)
) Engine = InnoDB;
```

The stock table indicates the number of items currently held at a particular warehouse, and
the cost of each item if it were to be delivered from that warehouse. For example, suppose
that the table contained the following rows:

```
                      pid wid quantity unitcost
                       1   1    10      23.50
                       1   2    15      22.95
                       1   3     7      22.00
```

This would indicate Warehouse 1 has 10 units in stock of Part 1 and each one costs $23.50,
while Warehouse 2 has 15 units in stock at a cost of $22.95 each, etc."

Suppose that you frequently need to answer questions of the form:

- What is the cheapest total cost of an order of 23 units of Part 1?"
- Where the number of units and the part id change from query to query.

In this case the cheapest way of supplying this order would be to purchase all 7 items in stock at Warehouse 3, all 15 from Warehouse 2 and just 1 item from Warehouse 1 at a total cost of
                    7  22:00 + 15  22:95 + 1  23:50 = 521:75

My question is to write a Java Method:

```
public double totalCost(int pid, int numItems)
```

that computes the cheapest total cost of supplying the specied number of units of part
with id pid. You may assume that the method has access to a variable conn that refers
to an already-created java.sql.Connection.

Java methods may NOT call the stored procedures of the following question

Comment: if it's homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: @MByD why does it matter if it is a homework question or not?

Comment: @bumperbox - because it will let people give an appropriate answer (without skipping the learning process)

Comment: it is not a home work actually.....am doing some practice question and came across this question

Answer (score 0):

Since this sounds like homework I will answer in a homework appropriate way.

Please take a look at this documentation about the class that you are talking about: [java.sql.Connection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Connection.html).

As you can see, it has a couple methods which can be used to create a [java.sql.Statement](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html).  With a `Statement` you should be able to run arbitrary SQL against a database.  This is probably where you want to be looking.

Good luck!